# How to give a message in bukkit after 60 seconds?

Tags: java, bukkit

thanks for all that helped me! I will be more detailed now. What I want to do is a Bukkit plugin which after one minute, and if the player dropped something, the console displays an information message, like "Players are moving", but I just can make the first message appear: "Player dropped something" and I think that the error is on the boolean that I used. Please, can anyone help me with bukkit? This is my code:

```
public class HgCake extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{
    boolean reference = false;
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onDropItem (PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
        getLogger().info("Player dropped something");
        reference = true;
    }

    public void onPlayerMove (PlayerMoveEvent e){
        if (reference = true){
            getLogger().info("Players are moving");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bukkit has a built in scheduling system that you can read up on 
[Scheduler Programming](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming)

Use this instead of normal Java timers, trust me. It'll make your life easier in the long run.

**To do what you're wanting to do, you'd need a `BukkitRunnable` class to give to the scheduler.**

This is a generic one I over-simplified for example purposes:

```
public class Callback extends BukkitRunnable{
        private Object targetObject;
        public Method targetMethod;
        private Object[] perameters;

        public Callback(Object targetObject, String methodName, Object[] argsOrNull){
                try {
                    this.targetMethod = targetObject.getClass().getMethod(methodName, (Class<?>[]) argsOrNull);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                this.targetObject = targetObject;
                this.perameters = argsOrNull;
        }

        public void run(){
                try {
                    this.targetMethod.invoke(this.targetObject,perameters);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

**Then you create an object of that runnable, providing the callback method/props as args, and give it to the scheduler to run in 60 seconds:**

For the movement part, you just watch that while the item is dropped and nobody's moved yet.

```
public class DropWatcher implements Listener {
    private Boolean hasAnythingMoved;
    private Boolean dropped;
    private Pwncraft plugin;
    private Player player;

    public DropWatcher(Pwncraft plugin, Player player){
        this.player = player;
        this.hasAnythingMoved = false;
        this.dropped = false;
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.plugin.pluginManager.registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    //Drop event listener: When the player drops an item, it sets dropped to true, and initiates the countdown.
    @EventHandler
    public void onDropItem (PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getPlayer().equals(this.player) && !this.dropped){
            this.dropped = true;
            BukkitCallbackTask doInSixtySeconds = new BukkitCallbackTask(this, "timesUp" , null);
            doInSixtySeconds.runTaskLater(plugin, 1200); // time is in ticks (20 ticks +/- = 1 sec), so 1200 ticks = 1 min.
        }
    }

    //Watches for other-players' movement, and sets hasAnythingMoved to true if so.
    @EventHandler
    public void onMove (PlayerMoveEvent e){
        if(!e.getPlayer().equals(this.player) && this.dropped && !this.hasAnythingMoved){
            this.hasAnythingMoved = true;
        }
    }

    /*
    This is the method the runnable calls when the timer is up.
    It checks for movement, and if so, sends a message and explodes the player 
    (Just because it can. You're welcome to veto the explosion.) 
    */
    public void timesUp(){

        if(this.hasAnythingMoved){
            this.player.sendMessage("Someone moved! Time to party!");
            this.player.getWorld().createExplosion(this.player.getLocation(), 5F);
            this.dropped = false;
            this.hasAnythingMoved = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `@EventHandler` for the PlayerMoveEvent I think.

It should be:

```
public class HgCake extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{
boolean reference = false;
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

@EventHandler
public void onDropItem (PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
    getLogger().info("Player dropped something");
    reference = true;
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove (PlayerMoveEvent e){
    if (reference = true){
        getLogger().info("Players are moving");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    int plannedActivity = getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLaterAsynchronously(this, new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            //whatever you want to do

        }

    }, 120L);
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer

Comment: For example, you may want to explain why the `delay` parameter is 120 when the OP asked for a 60 second delay.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), because they don't teach the solution.